# Explicit way to construct simple complex tori/abelian varieties of dimension at least 2

Tags: abelian-varieties, complex-geometry

The following question was motivated by one of the earliest exercises of [Complex Abelian Variaties by Birkenhake and Lange](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Complex_Abelian_varieties.html?id=MOW2gEP7HIkC) during my presentation last year.

It can be shown that any complex torus $X$ $(=V/\Lambda$, where $V$ is a complex vector space and $\Lambda$ is lattice of maximal real dimension in $V)$ admits at most countably many complex subtori.

My question:

> Is there sort of algorithm s.t. one could find simple (not admitting any non-trivial complex subtorus) complex tori of dimension $\geq 2?$ how about simple abelian varieties of dimension $\geq 2?$

Note that, $X$ admits a complex subtorus of dimension $g'$ if and only if there exists a subgroup $\Lambda' \subset \Lambda$ of rank $2g'$ s.t. the image of the canonical map $\Lambda' \otimes \mathbb{R} \to V$ is a complex subvector space of $V.$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recall that the Néron-Severi group of a complex manifold $X$ is the subgroup of $NS(X)\subset H^2(X, \mathbb Z) $ consisting of first Chern classes of holomorphic line bundles on $X$.
More algebraically, it is the quotient group $PicX/Pic_0X$, as results  from the exact sequence

$$    0\to     Pic_0X    \to  PicX \stackrel {c_1}{\to }NS(X)  \to 0         $$

Since a torus is Kählerian, it will have no divisor at all if its Néron-Severi group is zero.
You can find an explicit calculation of the Picard number $\rho (X)=rank_ {\mathbb Z}NS(X)$ of 2-dimensional tori [here, in the Appendix](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1982__32_4/AIF_1982__32_4_25_0/AIF_1982__32_4_25_0.pdf)

You  will see there for example a  calculation of the Picard number of the torus determined by the lattice in $\mathbb C^2$ of matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&ip&ir\\
0&1&iq & is
\end{pmatrix} 
\quad \quad (p,q,r,s \in \mathbb R) $$

To give a completely explicit example, if $ \; p=1,r=\sqrt 2, q=\sqrt 3, s=\sqrt 5 \;$ then the corresponding (highly non algebraic!) torus has no holomorphic divisor (=curve) whatsoever.

Comment: That's great! so how can we construct the period matrices of simple complex tori for any dimension $g \geq 2?$

Comment: You could try to generalize the easy calculations done  for dimension $2$  in the reference to higher dimensions .    
You could also have a look at Chapter VIII of Debarre's [Complex Tori and Abelian Varieties][1] and the references given there.  

[1]:http://ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=SMFAMS-11

Answer (score 8):

I don't really know what "some sort of algorithm" means, but here is a source of examples of simple abelian varieties. As you probably know, if $L$ is a lattice in $\mathbf{C}$ then $\mathbf{C}/L$ is an abelian variety (of dimension 1). Here are some examples of $L$ coming from arithmetic: take an imaginary quadratic field $K$ living in the complexes, and let $L$ be the ring of integers of $K$.

This construction generalises. Let $K$ be a "CM field", i.e. a totally imaginary quadratic extension of a totally real field $F$. Let $L$ be the integers of $K$. The embeddings $F\to\mathbf{R}$ extend to embeddings $K\to\mathbf{C}$ and the resulting map $L\to\mathbf{C}^n$, $n=\frac{1}{2}[K:\mathbf{Q}]$ has a Riemann form by some basic results in arithmetic. The resulting abelian varieties $\mathbf{C}^n/L$ are typically simple (and have endomorphism ring containing $L$, so quite big). Google for "CM abelian variety" for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That does not really answer my question. I think, I should have been more precise. By algorithm, I mean how to construct the period matrices associated with simple complex tori/abelian varieties. Moreover, the method you described was explained in the above given reference.  